# Automating SharePoint Foundation 2013 Backups

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2013, backup

I am relatively new to SharePoint and am trying to figure out how to automate the backups for my SharePoint Foundation 2013 server. I want to store the backups on a network share on a different server. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

You have a great article here [Plan for backup and restore sharepoint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261687.aspx)

Feel free to comment anything you don't understand. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

To automate SharePoint backup process, there are typically 2 steps:

1. Create 2 PowerShell scripts to do the backup using `Backup-SPFarm`
   One script for full backup and other script for differential backup
2. Create 2 Windows Scheduler Tasks to run these PowerShell scripts, typically
   One daily task for differential backup and one weekly task for full backup

Answer (score 0):

The best in the business is the Ola Hallegren script that large number of organizations use to maintain and manage the backups in SharePoint .

Link -

> https://www.sqlshack.com/ola-hallengrens-sql-server-maintenance-solution-installation-sql-server-backup-solution/

Ola’s SQL Server Maintenance Solution consists of various scripts that create jobs and stored procedures once installed on the SQL Server. The entire solution was designed by Ola Hallengren, an MCITP database administrator and database developer, who has been working with SQL Server since 2001. The solution consists of three parts:

SQL Server Backup
SQL Server Integrity Check
SQL Server Index and Statistics Maintenance